# If surviving the Killing Curse is as easy as having someone die for you, how is Harry the first ever to survive it?

Tags: harry-potter

Harry survived the Killing Curse because Lily gave her life to save his, and that's it. Similarly when Harry gave his life to save the people of Hogwarts, Voldemort couldn't kill anyone attending there so they are also made immune to the curse. So how has this never happened before?? No one in the history of the world has ever sacrificed themselves? Seems fishy.

Comment: What sources claim that it has never happened before?

Comment: Just to point out, though the linked question does as well, Harry wasn't saved *just* because LIly died for him.  He was saved because Lily died for him when she clearly had another choice.  She could have easily chosen to live, but instead risked (and, predictably, lost) her life for his.

Comment: @Parrotmaster The books? It's a pretty big part of Harry's significance.

Comment: @JohnDoe The quote, if I remember it correctly, is that "no one is known to have survived" the Killing Curse, except for baby Harry. That's different than Harry definitely being the first.